# auto update local git repo when pushed to origin

Tags: git, github

I am basically trying to run a webservice on my server. I want it to automatically update the local repo on my server when I push to github from my client.

I I tried using git hooks but I just couldn't get it to work, but I would really like to. My only other idea would be to create an endpoint on my server that gets called from a github action whenever something Is pushed on github. Are there any good solutions out there, or is there a good way to do that with git hooks?

Comment: You *can't* do this with Git hooks. Well, more precisely, GitHub can do this with Git hooks, but *you* can't. The hooks GitHub have provided to you, in turn, are GitHub events; these are the thing to use here. I don't have any further details though.

Comment: @torek are you talking about actual [git hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) or [github webhooks](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/webhooks)?

Comment: GitHub webhooks (but they're triggered, on GitHub, by Git hooks or equivalent, hence the "more precisely" above: GitHub may, or may not, use Git hooks to fire off GitHub's webhooks).

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a job for a CI/CD pipeline.

From GitHub's [CI/CD: The what, why, and how](https://resources.github.com/ci-cd/):

> (...) they form a “CI/CD pipeline”—a series of automated workflows that help DevOps teams cut down on manual tasks:
>
> - Continuous integration (CI) automatically builds, tests, and integrates code changes within a shared repository; then
> - Continuous delivery (CD) automatically delivers code changes to production-ready environments for approval; or
> - Continuous deployment (CD) automatically deploys code changes to customers directly.

*Please note that CI/CD is not an only GitHub thing - there are **many** solutions. For example, here's an Azure tutorial: [Create a CI/CD pipeline for GitHub repo using Azure DevOps Starter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops-project/azure-devops-project-github).*